# is there a way to change the field names after papulation in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

hi i want to change the name of _id to something else after populating my fields but add fields or projection wont work with populate.

```
await this.Model.findOne({ username }).populate({
      path: 'tasks',
      match: { folder: { $ne: null } },
      $addFields: { id: '$_id' },
      select: { _id: 0 },
    })
```

is there a way to change the fields in pipeline? I had a look at virtuals but that not I wanted they change the way of ref between the collections

Comment: You can assign a field's value to another field name - in an aggregation query or in a projection.

Comment: @prasad_ projection wont work in populate

Comment: use `$lookup` and `$project`